# Ordinary query to Zend format Query?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

manually I constructed a query... I'm facing struggle to construct in zend,

e.i select inside select

these is my query,

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t1.eventId,t1.start_date,t1.end_date, COUNT(*) pos FROM events t1
    LEFT JOIN events t2
      ON t2.start_date = t1.start_date AND t2.eventId <= t1.eventId
  GROUP BY
    t1.eventId,t1.start_date
  ) t
WHERE
  pos <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = $database->select ()
        ->from ('events AS t1', array (
        'eventId',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        new Zend_Db_Expr ('COUNT(*) AS pos')
    ))
        ->joinLeft ('events AS t2', 't2.start_date = t1.start_date AND t2.eventId <= t1.eventId', array ())
        ->group ('t1.eventId,t1.start_date');

    $outer_query = $database->select ()
        ->from ($query)
        ->where ('pos <= 3');
```